# Static syncronized method and non-static synchronized method can both work on static member variables and this can cause unexpected behaviour

Tags: java, multithreading

I syncronized a static method and a non-static method as follows:

```
public class Demo {

static int myvalue;

synchronized static public void getStatic() {

    myvalue = 2;
}

synchronized public void get() {

    myvalue = 1;
}
}
```

Then from the Thread 1 I called only the static method and from the Thread 2 I called only the non-static method.

As one call is locked on the object and the other on the class, there is no waiting to get the lock.

So, that means that both the functions can run at the same time.

Now, the fact is that both the functions work on static member variables (myvalue in the example). That can be a problem in a multi-threading application. Why do the Java creators didn't take this into account? What can be the right way of dealing with this type of situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why do the Java creators didn't take this into account?

They did, and thats why you have option to sync on a class and object levels.

> What can be the right way of dealing with this type of situation?

You must use `synchronized(Demo.class) {...}` in your get() method.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronized on a single object or class, e.g.

```
public class Demo {

    static int myvalue;

    static public void getStatic() {
        synchronized(Demo.class) {
            myvalue = 2;
        }
    }

    public void get() {
        synchronized(Demo.class) {
            myvalue = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work, as in the `static` method there is no `this` reference available. What you can do is synchronize on `Demo.class` in both cases.

Comment: But inside a static method there isn't the concept of "this".